# excel formula within vba 1004 error

Tags: excel, vba

I am comparing two columns and displaying the differences in another column. I have an excel formula that works but I need to use it in a vba macro. When I try to usie it in the macro though I get the error "Run-time Error: '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error". How can this be fixed?

```
Sub Macro2()

   Range("B2:B60").Formula = "=IF(COUNTIF($A:$A,$B2)=0, B2, "")"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

Quotation marks within a string need to be doubled-up so, instead of

```
Range("B2:B60").Formula = "=IF(COUNTIF($A:$A,$B2)=0, B2, "")"
```

use

```
Range("B2:B60").Formula = "=IF(COUNTIF($A:$A,$B2)=0, B2, """")"
```

but please note that this will give a circular reference error, as cell B2 (etc) will be referencing itself.

Maybe you are intending to write the new value to column C?  If so, use

```
Range("C2:C60").Formula = "=IF(COUNTIF($A:$A,$B2)=0, B2, """")"
```

Comment: Thanks, this just changes the B column to 0's. Do you know of a ways a way around this? In excel the formula works as expected.

Comment: @kit - the code just writes the formula into the Excel cell, so if you entered the formula in Excel manually you would also get a circular reference error.